# ipconfig windows flashes and disappears automatically

Tags: windows, windows-10, command-line, ipconfig

my ipconfig.exe app is opening and closing automatically and it happen in every 3-4 Mins﻿.How can i make it not opening and closing automatically?.

Comment: use ProcessMonitor to trace which other process starts ipconfig: https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-3-Process-Monitor, https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-4-Process-Monitor. now stop the causing tool

Comment: any update on this? Was ProcMon helpful?